# python format string thousand separator with spaces

Tags: python, string-formatting

For printing number with thousand separator,
one can use the python format string :

```
'{:,}'.format(1234567890)
```

But how can I specify that I want a space for thousands separator?

Answer (score 133):

Here is bad but simple solution if you don't want to mess with `locale`:

```
'{:,}'.format(1234567890.001).replace(',', ' ')
```

Comment: What is bad about it?

Comment: @kasimir It's hacky. But 7 years later I don't think that it's that bad.

Answer (score 36):

Answer of @user136036 is quite good, but unfortunately it does not take into account reality of Python bugs. Full answer could be following:

### Variant A

If locale of your platform is working right, then just use locale:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print("{:,d}".format(7123001))
```

Result is dependent on your locale and Python implementation working right.

But what if Python formatting according to locale is broken, e.g. Python 3.5 on Linux?

### Variant B

If Python does not respect `grouping=True` parameter, you can use locale and a workaround (use monetary format):

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
locale._override_localeconv = {'mon_thousands_sep': '.'}
print(locale.format('%.2f', 12345.678, grouping=True, monetary=True))
```

Above gives 12.345,68 on my platform. Setting monetary to False or omitting it - Python does not group thousands.
Specifying `locale._override_localeconv = {'thousands_sep': '.'}` do nothing.

### Variant C

If you don't have time to check what is working OK and what is broken with Python on your platform, you can just use regular string replace function (if you want to swap commas and dot to dots and comma):

`print("{:,.2f}".format(7123001.345).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", "."))`

Replacing comma for space is trivial (point is assumed decimal separator):

`print("{:,.2f}".format(7123001.345).replace(",", " ")`

Comment: `'{:,d}'.format` doesn't depend on locale. You might have confused it with `'{:n}'.format`.

Comment: On macOS you might have to specify the exact locale, as it will not pull the OS default one. So for example: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'sv_SE.UTF-8')

Answer (score 17):

This will set the locale environment to your default OS location:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

Then you can use:

```
"{0:n}".format(1234567890)
```

Comment: This doesn't add spaces.

Answer (score 16):

You'll have to use the `'n'` locale-aware number format instead, and [set your locale](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) to one that uses a space as a thousands separator. Yes, this is painful.

> `'n'` - Number. This is the same as `'d'`, except that it uses the current locale setting to insert the appropriate number separator characters.

Comment: " unsupported format character 'n' (0x6e) at index 1". Probably, this is only for Python 3?

Comment: @Vanuan: What version of Python are you using? I tested this with 2.6 and 2.7; 2.5 and older don't *have* `str.format()`.

Comment: @Vanuan: Or are you using `%` string formatting? That type of string formatting doesn't support `n`, in any Python version.

Comment: This works only with Integers. I am searching for a solution for floating point numbers.

Answer (score 10):

Lets say you code:

```
print(f'{name} | Yearly salary: ${salary}.')
```

> PRINTS -> Kate | Yearly salary: $60000.

First put a , separator:

```
print(f'{name} | Yearly salary: ${salary:,}.')
```

> PRINTS -> Kate | Yearly salary: $60,000.

Then replace the comma with a space:

```
print(f'{name} | Yearly salary: {salary:,} USD.'.replace(',', ' '))
```

> PRINTS -> Kate | Yearly salary: 60 000 USD.

*NB: Remember USD, $ or £, kroner etc. notation should match accordingly universal standards*

Answer (score 4):

Python community has it defined under [PEP 378](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/), where you can see that the main proposal includes `format()` function. So, by following that proposal, I suggest using the following:

```
format(1234567890, ',d').replace(',',' ')
```

Comment: Almost the same thing was already suggested by the top voted answer, 8 years before you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the local, a solution that works with every size of string :

```
    def format_number(string):
        j = len(string) % 3
        substrings = [string[3 * i + j:3 * (i + 1) + j] for i in                                         range(len(string)//3)]
        if j != 0:
            substrings.insert(0, string[:j])
        return " ".join(substrings)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
@app.template_filter()
def numberFormat(value):
    return format(int(value), ',d').replace(',',' ')
```

then call the filter if i'm showing the value on the page like this:

```
{{ value | numberFormat }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format a number with a space as a thousand separator in Python, there isn't a direct built-in way to do it like there is with a comma. However, you can achieve this in a couple of different ways.

**Option 1: Using a Custom Formatting Function**

You can create a custom function to format the number with spaces as thousands separators. Here's an example:

```
def format_number_with_space_separator(number):
    parts = []
    while number >= 1000:
        number, remainder = divmod(number, 1000)
        parts.append(f'{remainder:03d}')
    parts.append(str(number))
    formatted_number = ' '.join(reversed(parts))
    return formatted_number

number = 1234567890
formatted_number = format_number_with_space_separator(number)
print(formatted_number)  # Output: 1 234 567 890
```

This function breaks down the number into groups of three digits and inserts spaces as thousands separators.

**Option 2: Using String Manipulation**

You can also use Python's built-in formatting with commas and then replace the commas with spaces to achieve the desired format:

```
number = 1234567890
formatted_number = '{:,}'.format(number).replace(',', ' ')
print(formatted_number)  # Output: 1 234 567 890
```

This approach uses the built-in `:,` format specifier to insert commas as thousands separators and then replaces those commas with spaces.

I hope this helps you achieve the formatting you need!

Answer (score -4):

You can use an f-string:

```
number = 1234567890
f"{number:,.2f}"
```

Comment: This misses totally what was asked for: using *space* as thousands separator.