# Making a space between numbers

Tags: python

I've a little "cosmetic" problem with my numbers.
e.g. I want to show 3255643 as 3 255 643.
So how can I make this better-looking space between numbers?

Comment: I don't know why the other user removed their link
Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670125/python-format-string-thousand-separator-with-spaces

Comment: @Cireo: rather annoyingly, the default "Duplicate of x" message is stated *as if it's a question*: "Does this answer ..?" It automatically gets deleted when the question is closed.

Comment: Learned something new, thanks!  I don't mind it so much then, just should have its own channel and UX, not comments =\